# Laser diode spectrum vs LED spectrum, why so much difference in broadness?

Tags: visible-light, laser, light-emitting-diodes

I've been reading about how light is produced in both laser diodes (the most common types of lasers) and LED's.

The mechanism seems very similar if not exactly the same: one applies a potential difference through a semi-conductor material that emits light when the electrons recombine with holes in a p-n junction.
Thus I would have expected the broadness of the spectrum of both laser diodes and LED to be similar. However they aren't. Here's the spectrum of some LED's: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f4/Red-YellowGreen-Blue_LED_spectra.png.

While the spectrum of a laser can be found there: http://ondax.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/chart.jpg or there: http://ledmuseum.candlepower.us/rlspec4.htm.

We can see that the spectrum of a laser diode is much narrower in terms of wavelengths than that of a LED's one. I'd appreciate if someone could tell me why it is so or any reference where I can read the reason.

Thanks.

Comment: IANAP.  Isn't it just that the resonance set up within the laser cavity that prevents the wider frequencies from becoming coherent (and thus lasing) ?

Comment: That's the first thing that came to my mind but I was told that no, on IRC in the #physics channel. So I am not sure at all.

Comment: LASER= light amplification by stimulated emission of radiation. You probably pump by the diode light, but the light you get out is a result of an avalanche from one resonant state - an emission stimulated by other photons of the same resonant energy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you first apply current to a laser diode, it does behave as an LED. Light is output across a (relatively) broad spectrum by spontaneous emission.

But once the current reaches the threshold current, then positive feedback causes one (or a few) modes to oscillate. Further increases in input power will increase the ouput in those particular modes, but the gain will be pinned at the threshold level. Since gain is mainly a function of carrier density, this means the carrier density is also pinned, and spontaneous emission won't increase.

Similar gain-pinning mechanisms are seen in most laser systems.

Comment: Am I right if I say that for LED's the current does not reach that threhold reached by laser diodes?

Comment: @no_choice99: In principle yes. But I would use the slightly different wording  "A laser below threshold behaves as an LED" (because a LED has no threshold).

Comment: @no_choice99, the LED can't reach threshold and start lasing because there's no (or not enough) optical feedback (high-reflectivity  mirrors) like there is in a laser diode.